# Cannot read property 'canShow' of undefined - React-Native-FBSDK - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native

I've been trying to install the React-Native-FBSDK into my project following the exact path laid out here for iOS:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started

But every time when I go to actually use the ShareDialog, I get the error message `Cannot read property 'canShow' of undefined`. I've gone through the steps 3 times now with the same outcome every time. Is there something else I have to do to actually be able to use this with React-Native?

React-Native 0.42

React-Native-FBSDK 0.5

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this? Im running into the same issue

Comment: @DeanMWake Ya I just posted the answer below. Took me a couple days to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out why this happens. The documentation on the Facebook SDK website for react-native is wrong. You need to follow the readme in the github repo https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk.

What they don't mention in the readme is if you are trying to install the SDK into your Project instead of your documents folder there is a way. You'll probably want to do this with your React-Native Project if you are working as a team or use multiple machines to develop your app. Putting it in your Project just allows you to clone your repo and `npm i` and your done vs installing the sdk on every machine you use to develop then making sure xCode has the right path.

So when you are going through the iOS steps and it tells you to download and move the sdk to `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` you can actually put it directly inside your ios directory in your app under the Frameworks folder. (If it is not a Frameworks folder there just make one) Then just follow the rest of the steps and whenever it mentions `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` just use the files from `/ios/Framworks`.

Make note though, if you do decide to put the SDK inside your Project it will increase your repo size by 50-100MB. It is also good to remove the `Samples` folder from the SDK as they just take up space and are not needed.